# Get the value of a process executed in a grandchild back to child using Forks::Super

Tags: perl, fork

I'm looking for a solution to run asynchronous child processes which create their own children.

The grandchild processes typically run a shell command whose result is needed back in the child process.

I'd like to use [`Forks::Super`](https://metacpan.org/module/Forks%3a%3aSuper) because it includes other interesting features.

The code below works, but there are warnings saying that the child temporary files couldn't be deleted.

What do I do wrong?

```
use Forks::Super ':all';
$Forks::Super::CHILD_FORK_OK = 1;
use Proc::ProcessTable;

my %result;
for (;;) {
    $cnt++;
    if (($cnt %= 5) eq 0) {    #Start child if modulo 5 eq 0 (demo trigger)
        $child_pid = fork { sub => \&startChild };
        $result{$child_pid} = undef;     # We use only the hash key as identifier, the value is reserved for later usage
    }
    for my $pnt (sort keys %result) {    #maintain our internal process hash
        if (!&checkProcess($pnt)) {      #check our running childs
            print "PID $pnt has gone\n";
            delete $result{$pnt};
        }
    }
    sleep 1;
}    #endless

sub startChild {
    print "Starting Child $$\n";
    tie my @output, 'Forks::Super::bg_qx', qq["date"];
    sleep 2 + rand 7;
    print "Result was $output[0]\n";
    print "End  Child $$\n";
}

sub checkProcess {
    $tobj = new Proc::ProcessTable;
    $proctable = $tobj->table();
    for (@$proctable) {
        if ($_->pid eq $_[0]) {
            print "Found Child with PID $_[0]\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return undef;
}
```

The output is to long for the comment field, here are the recent lines of error:

```
Child 2767 had temp files!
    /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/README.txt
    /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_001
    /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_002.signal
    /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_003
    /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_004.signal
    at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Forks/Super/Job/Ipc.pm line 3115

Forks::Super::Job::Ipc::deinit_child() called
    at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Forks/Super/Job.pm line 1857
```

Comment: Copying error messages would be helpful too, I think, considering that everything else works.

Comment: The output is to long for the comment field, here are the recent lines of error: Child 2767 had temp files! /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/README.txt /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_001 /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_002.signal /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_003 /usr/local/dev/threading/.fhfork2767/.fh_004.signal
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Forks/Super/Job/Ipc.pm line 3115  Forks::Super::Job::Ipc::deinit_child() called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Forks/Super/Job.pm line 1857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just warnings messages, and they are superfluous if you are setting `$Forks::Super::CHILD_FORK_OK > 0`.

If they bother you, remove the line (line 3115 in `Forks/Super/Job/Ipc.pm`) or change it to something like

```
Carp::cluck("Child $$ had temp files! @IPC_FILES\n")
unless $Forks::Super::CHILD_FORK_OK >= 0;
```

and I'll clean this up in the next `Forks::Super` release.

Comment: So you're saying that the code looks OK and the warning can be ignored? I removed the lines which you mentioned and the code runs now without warnings. I'll then delete the temp files by my self, no worries with the new release. Your Module is great!!!

Comment: I just noticed that the temp file were deleted if i replace the lines as you mentioned above. Thats even better, less work. Thank you!